# JavaScript getting complete code of element when mouseover or onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I get the complete HTML code of the element I'm mouseovering or clicking?
Using `document.onmouseover = function(e){` can I get the full underlying HTML code of the element which triggered the event?

Right now, I am able to get the tag name or id or whatever.
What I would like is the whole code.

For example; if I'm mouseovering a table, I would like to get the string: `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE already has `element.outerHTML`

and this for others:

```
if (!('outerHTML' in document.documentElement)) {
    function getOuterHTML(element){
        var dummy = document.createElement('html');
        dummy.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
        var result = dummy.innerHTML;
        dummy.innerHTML = '';
        return result;
    }
}
else{
    function getOuterHTML(element){
        return element.outerHTML;
    }
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
 alert( getOuterHTML( document.getElementById("elementID") ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you would wrap the element with another, and call innerHTML on the wrapper, e.g.:

```
   document.onmouseover = function(e){
       var el = e.target;
       var p = document.createElement('p');
       p.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
       console.log(p.innerHTML);
   }
```

I would go with @David Murdoch's solution, which seems to be more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean just the structure, or the complete HTML code?

Just for the structure, you can use jQuery's `children()` function and iterate through them.

For the complete code, Internet Explorer has a property named `outerHTML`. To make this work in Firefox have a look at http://snipplr.com/view/5460/outerhtml-in-firefox/.

Comment: To David : do I need jQuery ?
To Tom : I will try this out. Thanks. We'll see if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're really asking, but I suspect you just want to get a string containing the HTML for the element you are mousing over. To that end, try the following:

```
function getMouseOverHTML(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  return event.currentTarget.parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

Then you can do whatever you like with that string of HTML markup.

Comment: Nice one too, but I prefer the outerHTML answer below.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the node, then insert it to another node and get the innerHTML for the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = window;

// Change "click" to "mouseover" to experment onmouseover EventListener version
w.addEventListener("click", function(evt)
{
    alert(evt.target.outerHTML);
}, false);
```

Description:

- **w** variable stores the element you aim to get the html content from, in this case it is the whole window element and all its children and sub children; of course you can assign to it the element you prefer getting a ref to it as you wish (i.e. getElementById... etc)
- **evt.target** returns the specific dom element on which you clicked
- **.outerHTML** returns the element's html; also you may want to replace it with **.innerHTML** to get the inner HTML (the HTML **contained INTO** the target element); replace it with **innerText** to get the inner text only.
- **alert()** function shows it into an alert message

working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zajcnezh/

Note that addEventListner is not cross browser compatible, my aim was not to do it this way but just to show a potential solution for the question. But if you need it cross browser, it is possible to easy modify the code snippet to achieve this aim too.